# where should be compilation in magneto2 kubernetes stack

Tags: magento2, docker, devops

I have conceptual question

Where should be the static-content:deploy and di:compile for magento2 production environment on a kubernetes pod

it should be in app image that push/build into your registry ?

so the pods will start the container with already build assets and proxy files

or it should somehow start build on pod-initialize  or after pod-initialize ?

please help me for best practice on magento2 kubernetes setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can and in my opinion should generate all files for production mode during release build, so the app image contains everything necessary while keep being target system independent. This way you

- generate just once wherever you deploy or scale
- encounter problems during build stage and not deployment stage
- keep your kubernetes deployments simpler and predictable